# c++ Floodfill algorithm crashes in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, flood-fill

I have a simple floodfill function, except it crashes with too much deallocating while running.

```
#include <vector>
cv::Mat fillLayer(cv::Mat filledEdge, int y, int x, int oldColor, float newColor){
    cv::Size shape = filledEdge.size();
    int h = shape.height;
    int w = shape.width;

    std::vector<int> theStackx = {x};
    std::vector<int> theStacky = {y};


    while (theStacky.size() > 0){
        y = theStacky.back();
        x = theStackx.back();
        theStacky.pop_back();
        theStackx.pop_back();

        if (x == w){
            continue;
        }
        if (x == -1){
            continue;
        }
        if (y == -1){
            continue;
        }
        if (y == h){
            continue;
        }

        if (filledEdge.at<float>(y, x) != oldColor){
            continue;
        }

        filledEdge.at<float>(y, x) = newColor;

        //up
        theStacky.push_back(y + 1);
        theStackx.push_back(x);
        //down
        theStacky.push_back(y - 1);
        theStackx.push_back(x);
        //right
        theStacky.push_back(y);
        theStackx.push_back(x + 1);
        //left
        theStacky.push_back(y);
        theStackx.push_back(x - 1);
    }
    return filledEdge;

}
```

The function that runs through floodfill is `fillSurface`. which runs through all the pixels in a Mat and fills them with a different color per floodfill

```
fillSurface(cv::Mat filledEdge, int oldColor) {
    std::vector<float> layers; //list all the different colors in mat
    cv::Size shape = filledEdge.size();
    int h = shape.height;
    int w = shape.width;
    float newColor;
    // run through all the pixels in Mat
    for(int y = 0; y!= h; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x!= w; x++){
            // only run floodfill if current pixel is oldColor
            if (filledEdge.at<float>(y, x) == oldColor){
                //newColor is random float to fill in to floodfill
                newColor = static_cast <float> ((rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX/253)) + 1); 
                // add newColor to list of layers
                layers.push_back(newColor);
                //run flood fill replacing old color with new color
                filledEdge = fillLayer(filledEdge, y, x, oldColor, newColor);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I receive:

```
Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7fea0d89dc00: probably modified after being freed.
```

The debugging I've done is far is set a breakpoint on malloc_error_break() to see where exactly I'm getting the break. It does lead to the floodfill function.

[image]

I'm wondering if there's anyway to fix this. If not, what would be the best alternative?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: It would also be interesting to know how big the filledEdge matrix is in your failing test case.  And, it would be useful for you to consider that you declared and initialized variables h and w but never used them.  Why didn't you use them after you created them?  You must have thought they'd be good for something.  What?  Maybe thinking about that would help you see an issue and _that_ could help you solve your crash.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I edited the question to add my debugging and further detail on code. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can't directly reproduce your problem without an MCVE and I don't know CV myself.  But I can make some guesses that could help.

The runtime error states "Incorrect checksum for freed object ...: probably modified after being freed."

The first hint that gives you is that heap checks such as this typically take place only when heap operations happen - not when the corruption occurs.  You don't have any explicit heap operations in your code (e.g., `new` or `delete`).  The heap usage here comes from well-documented and well-tested data structures from the standard library (`vector`) and cv (`Mat`).

The second hint is `probably modified after being freed` but this is incomplete - another possibility is some code writing outside of its bounds - either a buffer overrun or incorrect array indexing or something like that.

And that last bit brings us to the CV documentation for class Mat which does not mention anywhere what happens if you index the Mat badly.  It *does* have warnings about making sure you're accessing with the right element type or things could go wrong.  And those things together might be a very strong hint that if you access the Mat incorrectly bad things could happen.  Like, if you're writing, maybe memory corruption.

Those things together, along with my comment above about your declaring variables `h` and `w` but not using them - and so what exactly did you think you'd be using `h` and `w` for - should get you a long way towards figuring out how the heap got corrupted to the point where the runtime system complained about it.

Spoiler alert (for best results read only *after* you've solved the problem):

> Writing outside the bounds of the `Mat` because you never check the bounds of your indexes to keep them from exceeding the limits and apparently `Mat::at` doesn't check either (at least, the documentation doesn't say it does - you could verify that with an experiment).

Comment: I've added restrictions to make sure the pixel(y, x) doesn't go outside of mat(which is why I defined h and w). So far I guessing the script is crashing because of the massively extensive use of floodfill which runs `pop_back()` on a large dynamic vector(which leads to data corruption).  does that sounds like a possibility?

Comment: The image I'm running on are 224 x 224 in which the script crashes sometimes and works sometimes.

Comment: There should be no problems whatsoever with adding elements to or removing elements from vector, especially of a primitive type, until you run out of memory in your process - and that would look different (an out of memory exception would be thrown).  I see your modified code.  I would ask you to confirm, via experimentation or documentation, that you are subscripting your elements in the right order.  Though that shouldn't matter for a square image it would make a difference for rectangles.  I see you're passing oldcolor to fillLayer() as an int, newcolor as a float.  What does that imply?